# Get the items in same category in Laravel Many to Many Eloquent relationship

Tags: php, mysql, sql, laravel, eloquent

There is a category and product.

Category can be "Recommended", "Shoes", "Shirts" etc.. ,  product can be "nike shirts" , "Adidas shoes" etc..

```
Category
id
name

Product
id
name

CateogryProducts 
cat_id
product_id
```

I would like to get the next and previous product id from the product list, however, the list need to be in specific category.

For example, if I provide shoes category, then obtain the shoes list, and based on the product id , get the next shoes and previous shoes product id.

```
$this->data['category'] = Category::find($cat);
$product = Product::find($id);
$this->data['prev'] = Product::where('id', '<', $product->id)->max('id');
$this->data['next'] = Product::where('id', '>', $product->id)->min('id');
```

Here is my attempt to get the next / previous ID, are there any way to limit the list to the same category?

Thanks a lot

Comment: Did you check this ? https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/eloquent-relationships#polymorphic-relations

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have correctly set up relations you'll it will be fine to do:

```
$prev = Product::with(['categories' => function($query){
      $query->where('id', $cat_id);
    }])->where('id', '<', $id)->orderBy('id', 'desc')->first();

$next = Product::with(['categories' => function($query){
      $query->where('cat_id', $cat_id);
    }])->where('id', '>', $id)->orderBy('id', 'asc')->first();
```

It's not tested, maybe need some tweak and tune asc/desc in the right way you need it, but this is the way to go